# Javascript search not working as expected. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute search but it not working as per my expectation. It returning 0 instead 2. How to resolve it?

```js
var number = '4,4';
alert(number.search(/4/g));
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to return 2? `.search()` returns the index of the first match, not a count of matches. If a function doesn't seem to work the way you expected, the first thing to do is check documentation for that function, so please read [some `.search()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search).

Comment: @nnnnnn In string there 2 time 4.

Comment: @RushabhShah that is not the functionality of search(). It simply returns the position of the occurence of search term. Not the number of hits.

Answer (score 1):

`.search` returns the *index* of the match. `4` is matched at index 0 of the string, so it returns 0. If you wanted to check how many times 4 occurs in the string, use `.match` instead, and check the `.length` of the match object:

```js
var number = '4,4';
const match = number.match(/4/g);
console.log((match || []).length);
```

(the `|| []` is needed in case `match` is null, in which case you'd want 0, rather than a thrown error)

Comment: What if the input is `'4,44,4'`? The OP didn't provide clear requirements, but my guess is they'd probably want to match the 4s and not the 44. Still, good answer. +1

Comment: i think OP provided the regExp, he just wonder why regExp is not executed as expected

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to count the number of occurrences.

Use regex to store the occurrences and return the length to indicate the count.

```js
var temp = "4,4";
var count = (temp.match(/4/g) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

Comment: @ﾃﾞﾋﾞｯﾄ When I posted this, it wasn't answered, strange.

Answer (score 0):

The search() method searches a string for a specified value, and returns the position of the match. if you what to count the occurrences you must to make something like this:

```js
var number = '4,4';
var qtd = (number.match(/4/g) || []).length;
alert(qtd);
```

Comment: OK, this isn't wrong, but...two people already posted the same answer.